# sql query get total value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can I get these results through query:

```
Id --- Brand --- Price
1 -----Hp -------100
2 -----Hp -------200
3 -----Hp -------300
4 -----Acer -------100
5 -----Acer -------120
```

Into these:

```
Id --- Brand --- Total Price
1 -----Hp -------600
2 -----Hp -------600
3 -----Hp -------600
4 -----Acer -------220
5 -----Acer -------220
```

The brand and Id must be displayed like that.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Why this makes sense? Showing multiple times same values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `JOIN` for getting desired result

STEP 1- First try to get SUM of values which you want with below query

```
SELECT id, brand, SUM( price ) AS price
FROM  `items` group by brand
```

Output

```
id  brand   price
4   Acer    220
1   HP      600
```

STEP 2- Now apply LEFT join with base table to get final result

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.brand, t2.price
FROM  `items` t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT id, brand, SUM( price ) AS price
FROM  `items` 
GROUP BY brand
)t2 ON t1.brand = t2.brand
```

Output

```
id  brand   price
1   HP      600
2   HP      600
3   HP      600
4   Acer    220
5   Acer    220
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT
Id
,Brand
,(SELECT SUM(Price) FROM yourtable tb2 WHERE tb1.Brand = tb2.Brand) as TotalPrice
FROM yourtable tb1
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you so much.